# Adding year-1 to query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle18c

I have several categories, that have a corresponding timeseries in a VIEW, I would like to add a leading year to the query. The query I came up with is of the form:

```sql
SELECT CAT, ADD_MONTHS(MIN(DATE_REF),-12) DATE_REF FROM INFO GROUP BY CAT
UNION
SELECT CAT, DATE_REF FROM INFO GROUP BY CAT,DATE_REF;
```

I am uncertain of the performance implications of using UNION in the query and referencing the same view twice, thus wondering if there is a "better" way to get the same result?

[Example data and code in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a87a/1)

Data I have:

| CAT (VARCHAR2(2)) | DATE_REF (DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | '01.01.2021' |
| C1 | '01.01.2022' |
| C1 | '01.01.2022' |
| C2 | '01.01.2021' |
| C2 | '01.01.2021' |
| C2 | '01.01.2022' |

Data I want:

| CAT (VARCHAR2(2)) | DATE_REF (DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | '01.01.2020' |
| C1 | '01.01.2021' |
| C1 | '01.01.2022' |
| C2 | '01.01.2020' |
| C2 | '01.01.2021' |
| C2 | '01.01.2022' |

Execution plan for specific data and query:

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 12 | 144 | 10 | 00:00:01 |
| 1 | SORT UNIQUE |  | 12 | 144 | 10 | 00:00:01 |
| 2 | UNION-ALL |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | HASH GROUP BY |  | 6 | 72 | 5 | 00:00:01 |
| 4 | TABLE ACCESS FULL | INFO | 6 | 72 | 3 | 00:00:01 |
| 5 | HASH GROUP BY |  | 6 | 72 | 5 | 00:00:01 |
| 6 | TABLE ACCESS FULL | INFO | 6 | 72 | 3 | 00:00:01 |

Comment: what is the format of DATE_REF ? Could you provide an exemple of the data before and expected result

Comment: I am sorry, I see I was a bit unclear hope this clarifies what my end goal is.

Comment: Execution plan would help to clarify a performance question.

Comment: UNION ALL will improve performance

Comment: On 12 rows of data, I would not be concerned about performance.  Based on your description, you need to remove duplicates from the table.  Any method will incur additional overhead.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong about your need : you want to remove duplicated rows from your table and also add a row with a a year deducted from your lower record for each CAT value ?

Comment: @Jayvee UNION ALL might improve performance, but it may not give the desired results.

Comment: @BobC agree they do different things , union will also dedupe but that is not needed in this case as the OP is trying to add new rows